# Language Selector not Switching to Chinese

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I made a language selector its right from the docs, when I run the server I can switch to English, and Dutch. But, when I try and switch to Chinese it just goes back to english.
*Navbar.html*:

```
 <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
          <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
          <select name="language" onclick="Bonjour">
              {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
              {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
              {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
              {% for language in languages %}
                  <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code = LANGUAGE_CODE %}      selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                      {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
                  </option>
              {% endfor %}
          </select>
          <input type="submit" value="Go" />
      </form>
```

*Settings.py:*

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    ...
]
...

# Translations
USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

LANGUAGES = (
    ("en", u"English"),
    ("zh-cn", u"简体中文"),
    ('de', u"German"),
)
...
```

*Locale Paths:*
I have Dutch, and Chinese. They are under in the path `locales/` and the folders are called `de`, and `zh-cn`.
 
 
Let me know if you need to see more code, and from where.

Comment: I'm not fully up to speed on the details, but I understand that zh-cn has been deprecated - see https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/3668 . Perhaps changing it to `zh-hans` will work?

Comment: Whenever I change the name to `zh-hans` or `zh-Hans` this happens: [link](https://pastebin.com/kHmv9tgz)

Comment: Nevermind, I put an underscore instead of hyphens my mistake. But, it works thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gasman said: 
 "I'm not fully up to speed on the details, but I understand that zh-cn has been deprecated - see [github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/3668](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/3668). Perhaps changing it to `zh-hans` will work?" 
 Changing it to `zh-hans` just like that worked, and make sure you name the locale folder and the language name in `settings.py`.